# Yii2: Kartik DepDrop widget without child value show up

Tags: php, widget, yii2

I'm new in Yii2. I am using the DepDrop widget provide by Kartik. Now, I can pick data from column1, however, the related data in column2 doesn't show up. I can't even click on it.

Here is partial of the content of mysql table.

```
ID | name | sub_ID | category
1  | up   | 11     | T-shirt
1  | up   | 12     | jet
2  | shoe | 21     | nike
2  | shoe | 22     | adidda
```

Here is my `_form.php` code

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category')->dropDownlist(
ArrayHelper::map(itemcategory::find()->all(), 'ID', 'name'), ['id' => 'cat_id', 'prompt' => 'Select…']
);?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'subcategory')->widget(
DepDrop::classname(), [
   'options' => ['id' => 'subcategory', 'placeholder' => 'Select…'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'depends' => ['cat_id'],
        'url'=>\yii\helpers\Url::to(['/positemcategory/Subcat'])
    ]
]
)?>
```

Here is my model `ItemCategory.php` code

```
public function getSubCatList($cat_id)
{
    $data = self::find()->where(['ID' => $cat_id])->select(['sub_ID AS id', 'subcategory AS name'])->asArray()->all();
    return $data;
}
```

And here is the controller `Itemcategory.php` code

```
public function actionSubcat()
{
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $cat_id = $parents[0];
            // $out = \app\models\ItemCategory::getSubCategoryList($cat_id);
            $out = self::getSubCatList($cat_id);
            echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
}
```

I want to let user pick the item by its name, and save only the ID in another table in mysql instead of the full name.

Comment: I think code looks well (except of strange depdrop ajax url) and you've got to debug it step-by-step: 1. See whether is ajax called on category dropdown select. 2. See what $out you get after that.

Comment: I think maybe the url is the key, but I can't get the exact meaning of it according to the document. How could I send the correct content of subcategory to depdrop to display?

Comment: Seems duplicate. Answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832152/yii2-depdrop-kartik/29881160#29881160

Comment: [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBm3z3qIbR4)

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayHelper of Yii2.

```
 $out = self::getSubCatList($cat_id);
 echo Json::encode(['output'=>ArrayHelper::map($out,'id','name'),'selected'=>'']);
```

As a result you will get array with id as key and name as value.

Comment: `hi select("... as id")` does that already