# Yii2 DepDrop kartik

Tags: php, yii2

Ok I am trying to use the Kartik Depdrop widget, but get this error **500 (Internal Server Error)**

i have parent model Brand and submodel CarModel

Here are my files:

**CarsController.php**

```
public function actionSubcat() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $cat_id = $parents[0];
            $out = self::getSubCatList($cat_id);
            // the getSubCatList function will query the database based on the
            // cat_id and return an array like below:
            // [
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat-id-1>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name1>'],
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat_id_2>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name2>']
            // ]
            echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
}
```

model **Cars.php**

```
public function getSubCatList($cat_id)
{
    $data=\common\models\CarModel::find()
       ->where(['brand_id'=>$cat_id])
       ->select(['id','name_ru AS name' ])->asArray()->all();

    return $data;

}
```

and my viw file

```
<?php $catList = ArrayHelper::map(Brand::find()->all(),'id','name_ru'); ?>

<?=  $form->field($model, 'brand_id')->dropDownList($catList, 
    [
        'prompt' => 'Select brand',
        'id'=>'brand_id-id'
    ]);
?>

<?=$form->field($model, 'car_model_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
         'options' => ['id'=>'car_model_id-id'],
         'pluginOptions'=>[
             'depends'=>['brand_id-id'],
             'placeholder' => 'Select...',
             'url' => Url::to(['subcat'])
        ]
    ]);

?>
```

what is my mistake?

Comment: it would useful if you can post what internal server error you are having by posting the Yii2 log output ( ../runtime/logs/app.log)

Comment: print and show us your `$out` and `$_POST['depdrop_parents']`.

Comment: depdrop_parents[0]:1 
1 is my parent id 
and this my $out 
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(3) "318" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(3) "320" } }

Answer (score 3):

The code inside the controller

```
$out = self::getSubCatList($cat_id);
```

the following change

```
$out = Cars::getSubCatList($cat_id);
```

and define **getSubCatList** method to **static method**

```
public static function getSubCatList($cat_id)
```

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) again (

Comment: put content of file log here (**runtime/logs/app.log**)

Comment: I added the use yii \ helpers \ Json; and it worked))) 
thanks)